# FTP Active vs passive mode

Tags: ftp

I have a FTP server and while doing testing I found an odd issue that I don't understand. I send a RETR command on file "/Folder1/file.txt" and it works fine. Then I send a RETR command on file "/Folder1/SubFolder1/file.txt" and it times out on transfering the data to the client. This was in active mode. When I switch to passive mode it works fine.

I understand the difference between the two modes, but what I don't understand is why it worked for one file in active mode, but not the other. I tried it a dozen times and still got the same results.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It must be a configuration issue with your FTP server

Comment: That's what I'm thinking but I don't know what configuration would cause that...

Comment: Which server are you using ?, which platform ?

Comment: It's a server called CrushFTP running on Windows Server 2003 R2.

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged as both ftp and sftp.  They are two completely separate protocols.

Comment: Is there a firewall, proxy, or other packet-mangling mechanism between the client and server? Can you fetch /Folder1/file.txt more than once in active mode? Are you blocking ICMP (specifically "fragmentation needed") messages?

Comment: Yeah we have aload balancer that seems to be causing the issue with this one directory. When we go to one specific server it works fine, but when we go through the load balancer it fails. Time to chat with the network guys!

Comment: If it were me I would use SFTP "single port" server using NULL FTP Server .

Comment: @djangofan: I think you are thinking of FTPS, not SFTP. FTPS is essentially FTP over SSL, much like HTTPS is HTTP over SSL. SFTP is "SSH File Transfer Protocol" provided by SSHv2 (superseding the SCP (Secure CoPy) protocol offered by SSHv1) which is quite a different beastie. IIRC FTPS still has a passive/active distinction and uses multiple connections, SFTP (like SCP before it) uses a single connection usually over port 22 via a SSH server.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [official specification of the File Transfer
Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959), you'll find that:

> FTP can be run in active mode or
> passive mode, which control how the
> second connection is opened. In active
> mode the client sends the server the
> IP address port number that the client
> will use for the data connection, and
> the server opens the connection.
> Passive mode was devised for use where
> the client is behind a firewall and
> unable to accept incoming TCP
> connections. The server sends the
> client an IP address and port number
> and the client opens the connection to
> the server. Both modes were updated in
> September 1998 to add support for IPv6
> and made some other changes to passive
> mode, making it extended passive mode.

So, my first thought is that there's something wrong with your folder permissions. Double check them.

Comment: Folder permissions are all the same...

Comment: Based on this suggestion, I would start by disabling the IPv6 protocol on your server so that the IPv6 stuff isnt a factor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the first file was small enough to be acceptable to transfer on the same connection, but that the second file was larger.

Answer (score 1):

Although unlikely in this case another *conceivable* problem you may have is your client's firewall. Active FTP requires that the client open a TCP port to which the server connects for file transfer.

It is possible that the client's firewall has one extended port accessible but no more so the first file is allowed through that first port and not through any other extended ports (clients tend to allocate TCP ports in an incremental fashion).

Now with *passive FTP* the server allocates the TCP ports for transfer and the client connects to the server. In this case the client firewall can no longer cause much trouble because the client is connecting *to* the outside world (firewalls protect the outside world from connecting to within the firewall).

Almost always I find that switching from a broken active mode to a working passive mode indicates firewall problems.

Now for a diagram:

```
Active FTP

  client:n ---RETR portnum1---> server:21
  client:portnum1 <---fetches-- server:m1

  client:n ---RETR portnum2---> server:21
  client:portnum2 <---fetches-- server:m2

Passive FTP

  client:n ---PASV request----> server:21
  client:n <--PORT portnum1---- server:21
  client:n2 --fetches---------> server:portnum1

  client:n ---PASV request----> server:21
  client:n <--PORT portnum2---- server:21
  client:n3 --fetches---------> server:portnum2
```

Note that port 21 is the *command* channel. This is where instructions get sent to/from. Other ports are used for actual data transfer.