# Trying to connect to vsftpd, Failed to retrieve directory listing

Tags: ftp, nat, pfsense, vsftpd

I set up a FTP server on a virtual machine in my private network. I have an external ip address - `x.x.x.x` and use `pfSense` to forward ports. My FTP server is `vsftpd`, my OS is newest `Ubuntu 16.04`.

FTP internal address is `192.168.1.34`, external address of server itself is `x.x.x.x`.

I know I should forward both port 21 and 20, and I did it. Here'e NAT rules from `pfSense`:

[image]

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO

allow_writeable_chroot=YES

port_enable=YES
pasv_addr_resolve=NO
connect_from_port_20=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=40100
pasv_address=x.x.x.x
```

For me everything seems fine, but when I try to connect to my server, I'm getting `Error:   Connection timed out. Error:   Failed to retrieve directory listing.`

[image]

I did `sudo ufw disable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FTP Active vs passive mode](http://serverfault.com/questions/133870/ftp-active-vs-passive-mode)

Comment: Any chance you're trying to do passive-mode FTP, over SSL, through an adaptive firewall?

Comment: Port 40015 (256*156+79) is still closed.

Comment: @MadHatter: I want to configure passive-mode FTP, no SSL (at least now). I turned off all firewall, iptables etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do not translate the data ports in the pfsense NAT rule. Inbound to dest port 400xx needs to connect to 400xx on the vsftpd server, not the 20+xx as you have now.